# Resource file based dailog box banner load late in VC++ project

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a progress dialog with a image above progress-bar. This dialog is in a C++ project resource file. This dialog have "CONTROL" for image control.
Now this image is not displayed when dialog is displayed initially but after few seconds image and button appear

> **How to load image and button on first load itself?**

***Dialog displayed when called***
[image: First load]

***Dialog updated after 2 seconds***
[image: second load]

***Resource.rc***

```
IDD_TESTDIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 335, 74
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
EXSTYLE WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_TOPMOST
CAPTION "Connecting.."
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,277,54,50,15
    CONTROL         "",IDC_PROGRESS1,"msctls_progress32",WS_BORDER,12,61,254,6
    LTEXT           "Waiting for server connection...",IDC_PROGRESS_MESSAGE,13,44,181,14
    CONTROL         IDS_APP_TITLE,IDC_BITMAP1,"Static",SS_BITMAP,0,0,333,34
END
```

***Main.cpp***

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:     
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        //return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_PAINT:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    case WM_CLOSE:      
        ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_HIDE);
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDCANCEL:
            //DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_HIDE);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

// Creating Dialog
g_hToolbar = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_TESTDIALOG), hWnd, DialogProc);
```

Comment: Calling DefWindowProc in dialog is bad idea. You dont know, what you doing. First, read documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469(v=vs.85).aspx. "Although the dialog box procedure is similar to a window procedure, it must not call the DefWindowProc function to process unwanted messages"

Comment: @user2120666 After replacing `return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);` with `return (INT_PTR)TRUE;` dialog is shown but it is empty even progress bar(`msctls_progress32`) and `LTEXT` are not updated.

Comment: my query is why resource file based dialog are not loading properly

Comment: Because you doing wrong way. Your DialogProc is too bad. For example why you have WM_PAINT message? And how you update progress bar? I dont see any PBM messages.

Comment: Please read MSDN's reference on dialog boxes and perhaps a good guide, such as the Petzold book. Dialogs are, for better or for worse, a different world coding-wise than normal windows are, and it's too late to debate on the merits of the API design. You will have to make the necessary adjustments carefully rather than blindly (as it seems to have been done here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The problem was with the resource file.**

http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32Visibility.htm

We need to add **WS_VISIBLE** flag to resource dialog. By default, windows creates a hidden window unless the application specifies the WS_VISIBLE style. Typically, an application sets the WS_VISIBLE style after it has created a window to keep details of the creation process hidden from the user.

**Resource.rc**

```
IDD_TESTDIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 335, 74
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE
EXSTYLE WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_TOPMOST
CAPTION "Connecting.."
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,277,54,50,15
    CONTROL         "",IDC_PROGRESS1,"msctls_progress32",WS_BORDER,12,61,254,6
    LTEXT           "Waiting for server connection...",IDC_PROGRESS_MESSAGE,13,44,181,14
    CONTROL         IDS_APP_TITLE,IDC_BITMAP1,"Static",SS_BITMAP|WS_VISIBLE,0,0,333,34
END
```

Comment: :)  That has been taken care of, Thanks :)